# Bind secure server and authentification

Tags: ssl, dart

I would make a secure server, I have follow this [tutorial](http://jamesslocum.com/post/70003236123).

It work, but I would know how I can use .p12 certificate or .cer.

And when I 'bindSecure' my server, I request a certificate. But when I try to connect, after have choose a client certificate, I get an error (`net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`). I did something wrong ?

```dart
    if (!args.contains('--setup'))
        SecureSocket.initialize(database: config['SSLpath'], password: config['SSLpass']);

    HttpServer.bindSecure(config['Host'], config['SSLport'], certificateName: config['SSLname'], requestClientCertificate: true).then((server) {
        getRoute(server, _virDir);
    }).catchError((e) => throw "An error occured: ${e}.");
```

I use keychain on Mac OS for generating certificate.

Comment: It would be helpful to add the error you got to your question.

Comment: I'm sorry. The question is update.

Comment: Where do yo get this error? On the client or on the server? Is this a Dart error or a Browser error? What happends when you connect to the server using the example code of the blog post 'Connecting to a Secure Server'?

Comment: Have you tried with hardcoded values instead of `config['xxx']`? I think it could be helpful if you put 'real' values into the example code in your question. Of course you can anonymize all security relevant values. But often it makes a difference for example if you bind to 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', or some other IP addr.

Comment: The error appears on browser. I bind with 127.0.0.1. Maybe I should try with other value.

Comment: I searched for the error message and found a lot of results which say that a browser setting has to be adjusted. I would suggest try the code example from the blog to connect to the server. This way you keep the browser out of the equation and maybe you get a better error message.

Comment: Doesn't work with different address binding, and not at work too... All browsers returns the same error. (My server don't crash)

Comment: If I clic on 'cancel' when the browser ask me for a certificate, it work. But not if I choose one of my certificate

Comment: The method for programming secure sockets in Dart has changed, with version 1.13 and newer using BoringSSL rather than NSS as its implementation library.  The new interface uses PEM files and a SecurityContext object instead of an external certificate database.  See https://www.dartlang.org/server/tls-ssl.html for instructions on how to use the new interface.